# TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputText' of undefined because of naming convention i used like "lunchCtrl.iform.inputText"

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error when i click the button without entering anything in input field. I am seeing this is because of the naming convention as "lunchCtrl.iform.inputText". when i use this as "lunchCtrl.inputText" or just "inputText" in controller and html its going good without error for empty value onbutton click.
if i enter any text and click the button its going good.

can anyone help me whats going wrong here.
i have attached the code in the following jsfiddle [here][1]. please help me to find the reason.

https://jsfiddle.net/29bmy95j/

code for here:
**index.html**

## Lunch Checker

```
     <div class="form-group">
         <input id="lunch-menu" type="text"
         placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
         class="form-control" ng-model="lunchCtrl.iform.inputText">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="checkTooMuch()">Check If Too Much</button>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group message">
       <!-- Your message can go here. -->
     </div>
     Entered values::{{lunchCtrl.iform.inputText}}
     <p ng-bind="errorMsg" style="color:red"></p>
```

**App.js:**

```
var app=angular.module('LunchCheck', []);
app.controller('LunchCheckController', ["$scope",function($scope){
//function for checkTooMuch() ng-click event
$scope.checkTooMuch=function(){

    var inputfieldVal=$scope.lunchCtrl.iform.inputText;
    $scope.inputfieldValScope=inputfieldVal;
    var array=inputfieldVal.split(',');
    //$scope.array=array;
    var arrLen=array.length;
    if(arrLen > 3){$scope.errorMsg="Too much!";}
    else{$scope.errorMsg="Enjoy!";}
}
}]);
```

[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1POTz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$scope.lunchCtrl.iform` is not defined, thus initially when you don't type anything in the textfield `$scope.lunchCtrl.iform.inputText` will trigger an error.

```
$scope.checkTooMuch=function(){

    var inputfieldVal=$scope.lunchCtrl.iform.inputText;//error
```

So the fix would be to

**OPTION 1**

write a check and avoid:

```
$scope.checkTooMuch=function(){
    if (!$scope.lunchCtrl.iform.inputText){
       return;
    }

    ...your code
```

**OPTION 2**

Define your variable like below in the controller

```
app.controller('LunchCheckController', ["$scope",function($scope){
    //var v=$scope.inputText='';
    this.iform = {inputText:""};
    ...
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/en77ypoq/)

Comment: But i have a doubt here.
In this case if i check the "arrLen" without entering anything in input field,I am getting as "1". i think it should be "0". i am wondering why its "1" with the solution you provided.